# How to search Laravel object collections

Tags: laravel, collections

When I have a collection of objects, the only way I can find a particular object based on one of its attributes is as follows:

```
$key = $objects->search(function ($object) use ($comparator) {
    return $objects->attribute === $comparator; });
$object = $objects->get($key);
```

As you can see, I need to do it in two steps.  First I find the key, then use it to pull the object from the collection.

Is there an easier way?  For example, it would be great to do the following:

```
$object = $objects->mySearch('attribute', 'comparator');
```

Comment: Not sure but why can't you use `where` method in collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

$object = $objects->where('attribute', 'comparator');

or get the 1st one.

$object = $objects->where('attribute', 'comparator')->first();

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like this:

```
$object = $objects->map(function($object) use($comparator) {
    return ($object->attribute == $comparator) ? $object : null;
})->filter()->first();
```